# deleting the element that is smaller than left side element in array

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, performance

I'm trying to write a program whose input is an array of integers, and its size. This code has to delete the elements which are smaller than the element to the left. We want to find number of times that we have repeat this action to not be able to delete any more elements. Here is my code, it works but I want it to be faster.

Do you have any idea to make this code faster, or another way that is faster than this?

For example, given the array [10, 9, 7, 8, 6, 5, 3, 4, 2, 1], the function should return 2 because [10,9,7,8,6,5,3,4,2,1] → [10,8,4] → [10]

```cpp
int numberOfTimes(int array[] , int n) {
    int count = 0;
    int flag = 0;
    int sizeCounter = 0;
    while (true){
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; ++i) {
            if (array[i]<= array[i+1]){
                sizeCounter++;
                array[sizeCounter] = array[i+1];
            } else{
                flag = 1;
            }
        }
        if (flag == 0)
            return count;

        count++;
        flag = 0;
        n = (sizeCounter+1);
        sizeCounter = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you didn't need to return the count, then this could be done in one pass by keeping the maximum element seen in memory. But I struggle to find a way to "guess" the count this way. Although this does seem reminiscent of a classical problem with a clever solution, if I can find it again.

Comment: I'm having trouble reconciling the problem with the code presented.  It doesn't help that there are multiple ways to interpret the problem, but I don't think the code is right for any of them.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I didn't test the code, but it does not seem in disagreement with my interpretation of the problem. Unless I'm understanding something wrong, the code is erasing elements which are smaller than the element directly on their left. At the end of the for-loop, `sizeCounter` is equal to the size of the new array, after having removed those elements.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The "erasing" is achieved by maintaining two indices to the array: `i` which increases by 1 at every iteration of the for-loop, and `sizeCounter` which only increases by 1 when the element at `i` shouldn't be erased.

Comment: @Stef can you explain your way that  could be done in one pass by keeping the maximum element seen in memory?

Comment: If this is working code that you want reviewed, you may get a better response at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Problems with the code include incrementing `i` after loop iterations in which an element has been deleted and the array contents consequently shifted; and running `i` all the way to `n - 2` even though by the end of that iteration that may be beyond the end of the valid data.  There's probably more.

Comment: @asd `int max = array[0]; int sizeCounter = 1; for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) { if (max > array[i]) { max = array[i]; } else { sizeCounter++; } }`. But as you can see it doesn't compute `count`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I disagree with the issues you mention. Note that the value of `n` is modified at the end of the while-loop.

Comment: I don't have the complete solution, but I'd start by identifying peaks, valleys, downslopes, and upslopes. For example, in the array [10,5,3,4,6,8,7,1], the peaks are 10 and 8, the valleys are 3 and 1, the downslopes are `10,5,3` and `8,7,1`, and the upslope is `3,4,6,8`. Downslopes are removed in a single pass. Upslopes get removed at the rate of 1 element per pass. So this example has a count of 4 because the longest upslope has four elements and the peak 8 is less than the peak 10.

Comment: btw: I tested the code and it works.

Comment: What is the maximal size of array? What is the range of values in the array?

Comment: @tstanisl most size is 10^5

Comment: You can reformulate this problem and solve the equivalent: take the maximum "distance" of each element, where the "distance" of `array[i]` is `i - j`, with `j` being the closest index to the left of `i` satisfying `array[j] > array[i]`. If no such `j` exists, `array[i]` won't be deleted. This equivalent problem can be done in linear time.

Comment: @wLui155 But this problem is not equivalent. Consider this example: array=[10,8,7,6,9] → [10,9] → [10]. The answer is 2. Yet for `i=4`, we get `j=0`, and `i-j = 4.`

Comment: @Stef Good catch. My definition of "distance" in this sense wasn't quite right; it should be synonymous with the number of rounds it takes to delete an element. It turns out that the correct "distance" definition is recursive, which makes things a little trickier: `distance[i] = max(distance[j]) + 1`, for each `j < i`, if `array[j] < array[i]`. If no such `j` exists, `distance[i] = 0`. Fortunately, this problem is also solvable in linear time, which does meet the size of 10^5 constraint.

Comment: @wLui155 sorry but I dont get your idea can you explain it more please?

Comment: I'm basically claiming that the number of rounds it takes to delete `array[i]` is either 1. `0` (`array[i]` not deleted) 2. `1` (its neighbor `array[i - 1] > array[i]`) or 3. Find the closest element on the left larger than `array[i],` `array[k]`. Then the number of deletions is *one more than the largest number of rounds to delete some intermediate element between indices `k` and `i`*. As described the problem looks like it requires O(N^2) time to solve but with some clever manipulation it can be done much faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem can be solved in O(n) time and O(n) space using "monotonic stack".

For each element of the `array` we will find the number of "actions/turns" it takes to delete the element. In other words, how many turns have to pass, so that all elements between current element (inclusive) and the closest larger element to the left are deleted.

If we know that number (let's call it `turns`) then we can find maximum of this value for all elements of our array and we'll know the number of turns it takes to remove all elements from the array that can be removed. We'll have our answer.

Now, how do we find that `turns` value? It's easy, if we have these `turns` values computed for all elements to the left of the current element. We just find the closest element that is greater than current element and find the maximum number of `turns` for every element in between that element and the current element. I.e. if current element is at index `i`, and closest greater element is at index `j` (`j < i` and `array[j] > array[i]`), `turns[i] = max(turns[k]+1), for k in [j+1..i-1]`.

If we do this naively, finding `turns` for each element would be O(n). Fortunately, it's easy to see, that when we've found `j` for some `i`, we won't ever need to consider elements between `j` and `i` ever again. Remember, `array[j] > array[i]` and everything in between `j` and `i` is smaller than `array[i]`. We're looking for the closest array element that is greater than some value, so, if `array[i]` is not an answer, the whole `[j+1..i-1]` range is also not an answer, we can go straight to `j`.

Having this in mind, we arrive to the monotonic stack. Instead of storing `turns` for every element of `array`, we store it only for the strictly decreasing subsequence of `array` that we've visited so far.

Before adding new element to the stack, first we need to remove every element that is smaller than the current element. Then the top of the stack will be our `array[j]`.

As each element is added to the stack and removed exactly once, amortized cost of finding `turns` for each element is O(1), so the whole algorithm is O(n). In worst case the size of the stack grows to the same size as the array (if `array` is strictly decreasing). So the space complexity is O(n).

Here is the code (python):

```py
array = [10, 9, 7, 8, 6, 5, 3, 4, 2, 1]
s = [] # monotonic stack of pairs (array[j],turns[j])
count = 0 # result: number of turns to delete all deletable elements

for el in array:
  # initially assuming current element can be deleted
  turns = 1 
  
  # peeking at the top of the stack
  while len(s) > 0 and s[-1][0] <= el:
    _,t = s.pop()
    turns = max(t+1, turns)

  # corner case: current element is the largest so far, cant be deleted
  if len(s) == 0:
    turns = 0
  s.append( (el, turns) )
  count = max(count, turns)

print(count)
```

Tests:

```
[10, 9, 7, 8, 6, 5, 3, 4, 2, 1] → 2
[10, 9, 7, 8, 6, 5, 3, 4, 2, 1, 9] → 3
[10, 9, 7, 8, 6, 5, 3, 4, 2, 1, 11] → 2
[] → 0
[1, 2, 3] → 0
[1, 2, 3, 1] → 1
[10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] → 5
```

---

UPD: I've just read the comments and I'd like to give kudos to @wLui155, who came up with the same core idea before me.